# WP7 mp3 waveform

Tags: windows-phone-7, mp3, waveform, mediastreamsource

is there a way to display Waveform of an mp3 song in WP7 ?
I tried to play around with MediaStreamSource but nothing really worked out.

Thanks, Michal

Answer (score 0):

There is no stock component that does that. Your best option at this point is build your own, given that you are directly reading the frequencies from the MP3 file you are talking about.